# Submit action message is showing when refresh the page

Tags: php

When I refresh/reload the page the message(*Host Name, User Name and Database Name are mandatory.*) is showing. I prefer to show the message only after the submission of form.

Consider my **index.php** page:

```
// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE $dbname";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "<div class='msg'>Database created successfully</div>";
} else {
    echo "<div class='msg'>Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($conn) ."</div>";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
}else{
echo "<div class='msg'>Host Name, User Name and Database Name are mandatory.</div>";
}
}?>
<form method="post" action="index.php" class="dbform" >
<table>
<tr><td>Host Name</td><td><input type="text" name="hostname" value="localhost"></td></tr>
<tr><td>User Name</td><td><input type="text" name="username"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="text" name="pass"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Database Name</td><td><input type="text" name="dbname"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="subbtn" value="Create"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**Expected bahaviour:** When click the submit button, if the fields are empty show the `Host Name, User Name and Database Name are mandatory.` message,  It is working ok.

But when I refresh the page the message is also showing. How can I solve this?

Comment: close ?> php end tag before <form> tag start

Comment: I am not getting any error in your code

Comment: The submitted form will be there until you navigate the page or unset the previous post.So whenever you are refreshing after submitting the form the submit function calls

Comment: Can you post complete `index.php` code? How many `if-else` are there? Here  the code is not completely given

Comment: this is the complete code..

Answer (score 0):

It's because the browser is reloading the last request you performed on that page, which is a `POST` request to the `index.php`.
When you hit reload it is again performing that same request.

Most browsers ask for a confirmation before resubmitting a post request.

What you can do solve you problem is store your messages in session and redirect to the page.

Start of your PHP code add

```
session_start();
```

Then store your messages in session

```
$_SESSION['msg'] = 'Your message';
```

Then when you have processed the current request redirect.

```
header('Location: YOUR_URL');
die();
```

Then you can check if there is any message and output

```
<?php if (!empty($_SESSION['msg']) : ?>
    <div class='msg'><?php echo $_SESSION['msg']; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```